# SpeechSynthesis resumes on its own when iFrame is loaded, in firefox browser. Is that a limitation of SpeechSynthesis?

Tags: javascript, speech-synthesis

I am using speechSynthesis web api in my web application, I have created one toggle button which starts, pauses and resumes speechSynthesis.
Also I have created one more button which sets a source to an Iframe.

While running the app in firefox browser speechSynthesis is resuming on its own when I set a source to an Iframe.

Here's my code (index.hrml):

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    var btnState = 'Start';
    var ttsState = 'completed';
    function toggleTTS() {
      if (btnState === 'Start') {
        if (ttsState === 'completed') {
          StopTTS();
          ttsState = 'started';
          speak(document.getElementById("speakText").innerText);
          document.getElementById('toggleBtn').innerHTML = "Pause";
        } else {
          ResumeTTS();
        }
        btnState = 'Stop';
      } else {
        PauseTTS();
        btnState = 'Start';
        document.getElementById('toggleBtn').innerHTML = "Resume";
      }
    }
    function StopTTS() {
      speechSynthesis.cancel();
    }
    function PauseTTS() {
      if (!speechSynthesis.paused && speechSynthesis.pause) {
        speechSynthesis.pause();
      }
    }
    function ResumeTTS() {
      if (speechSynthesis.pending || speechSynthesis.paused) {
        speechSynthesis.resume();
      }
    }
    function speak(text) {
      var u = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text);
      u.lang = 'en-US';
      u.onend = (e) => {
        console.log('completed')
        ttsState = 'completed';
        btnState = 'Start';
        document.getElementById('toggleBtn').innerHTML = "Speak";
      };
      speechSynthesis.speak(u);
    }
    function setSrc(){
      document.getElementById('dummyIframe').src = "index.html";
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="toggleBtn" onclick="toggleTTS()">Speak</button>
  <button id="setSrcBtn" onclick="setSrc()">SetSrc</button>
  <div id="speakText">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
  <iframe id="dummyIframe"></iframe>
</body>
<html>
```

Steps to reproduce the bug:

1. Start speechSynthesis by clicking on "Speak" button and pause it in between.
2. Now set a source to an iframe by clicking "setSrc" button.

**Expected result**: SpeechSynthesis should remain in pause state.

**Actual result**: SpeechSynthesis resumes on its own in firefox browser.

Note: This is only happening in firefox browser not on any other browsers.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Frazer It's my web application requirement. I want to load something in my iFrame. I have tried calling **speechsynthesis.pause()** method inside iFrame's onload function, but no luck! **speechsynthesis.resume()** method gets called on its own in firefox when we load an iFrame.

Comment: I cannot recreate the problem if a different page is loaded into the iFrame, even one with speechsynthesis. Do you really want to load the same index page into the iFrame? If so why?

Comment: @Frazer No. I don't want to load the same page. I want to load some other page. And it's not necessary to have speechSynthesis inside that page.

Here's one dummy plunker which is almost similar to my app.
[https://plnkr.co/edit/uDviOdOBCzzUDWQBvmLu?p=preview]

Here there are 2 iframes one is by default created and one gets created on the fly. When we run speechSynthesis in one iframe and pause it and now when we create second iFrame speechSynthesis resumes.

Answer (score 0):

On your html2 script remove if(elem !== null) elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);

Same file add this to the end:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  show2();
  show1();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Although I know the issue gets resolved if we create second iframe already in the dom and just show/hide it as per our need. But for my application I **want to create it dynamically** on click of a button, also want to remove it when its not needed. As per my observation I think speechSynthesis gets confused when we try to load any iFrame and fires its resume() method.

Comment: Yes there seems to be a Firefox bug. However this resolves the problem as you have detailed it with code and as such you should accept the answer.